# exim4 reading relays from file (debian lenny)

Tags: debian, exim

I'm trying to make exim4 read the relay hosts from a file. i tryed lsearch:

```
# /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf 
dc_relay_domains='lsearch;/etc/exim4/relay_domains'
```

but it produces a warning and doesent work...

```
WARNING: using 'lookup;' constructs in /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf has never been supported!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `man update-exim4.conf` indicates to do in those cases is to locally set the macros creating the `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros` and putting your macros in it.
The macro you need is `MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS`, so your local macros file should include:

```
MAIN_RELAY_TO_DOMAINS = lsearch;/etc/exim4/relay_domains
```

After you restart exim you can check the `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated` and see that it was correctly added.

Comment: my update-exim4.conf didnt care about exmi4.localmacros, but i included it in the main section of exim4.conf.template...

Comment: Ouch sorry, the correct filename is `/etc/exim4/exim4`. The template works (actually, the first version of my answer was suggesting it) but there are cases where the template can be regenerated and you will lose the work, localmacros is safer.